# Creating map legend in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, legend

Finished all my analysis and would like to make a legend to display the data in the map I have.

Answer (score 9):

In ArcMap 9 and 10 you can go to Insert > Legend in layout view, and follow the GUI to create & format the legend.